# error 0x80004005 when connection to access db

Tags: c#

I am new to c# language

I was trying to `Connect to Access DB via C#`

but whenever I try to connect,  I get a `0x80004005 not a valid file name`

I am certain of the data source and file name

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
namespace db_access
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=‪D:\GmTool.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
                conn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Succesfull");
                conn.Close();
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error with Connection" + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code

hope you can help :)

Comment: nothing else in the exception besides the error code?

Comment: Try compiling your code for 32 bits (right click on your c# project -> properties-> Build -> Platform target => try setting it to x86.

Comment: What's your version of office and windows?

Comment: since you are also using `OleDb` try using the correct Exception change your catch block to use the following `catch (OleDbException ex)` and to get the correct error write `MessageBox.Show("Error with Connection" + ex.Message);`

Comment: i tried to set it to 32bit same problem

Comment: checkout the following site for information on 64bit http://www.connectionstrings.com/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments/

Comment: when i used ex.Message 
it showed the line Error with Connection not a valid file name

Comment: i tried adding the db file to resources

Comment: and added a datagridview 
and it worked fine
i need the connection to perform search operation

Comment: The D drive is an actual physical drive, or a mapped share?

Comment: actual driver
the visual basic version is 32bit
and microsoft access is 64bit
i was using 64bit db engine
when i deleted it and installed 32bit engine
the error turned to "provider is not registered on the local machine"

Comment: and now i couldnt even load a db to resource